# ListView size is not changing when I create a new ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have a ListViue with a button to remove items, which works fine.  I have a reset button that suppose to undo all the removes and have all the original items in the list box, but after pressing that button, there is still only 1 item in list not 4. The getView only gets called 1 time after I refresh the data and I can see the ArrayList do now have a size of 4.

I put a break point at the ArrayAdapter's getView method.  The list box starts out with 4 items and getView is called 4 times.  Each time I remove a item it gets called 1 less time, thus working.
this is the code (it's in my custom array adapter)
to remove a item

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code to remove a item
void removeItem(int id) {
    orderPrice.remove(id);
    orderVol.remove(id);
    orderStartDate.remove(id);
    orderEndDate.remove(id);
    orderType.remove(id);
    orderId.remove(id);
    // invalidate ListView
    doOutsideClass( t );
    ted++;
}    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This does not work, I remove 3 items from the listvuw (pressing my remove button 3 times) so there is one item in ListView. I then press the refresh button to call the method refreshListData ListView still only shows 1 item, From the debugger I see the new objects do have 4 items, but the getView method is only being called 1 time.

```
boolean refreshListData() {

    // add 1 order
    adapter.orderPrice=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderPrice);
    adapter.orderVol=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderVol);
    adapter.orderType=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderType);
    adapter.orderId=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderId);
    adapter.orderStartDate=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderStartDate);
    adapter.orderEndDate=new ArrayList<>(mParent.orderEndDate);

    return true;
```

The code does not work on GetView the listarrays have change but the arrayadapter only calls getrView 1 time, seems like it does not see the change in size

void filterRemoveItem(int pes) {
        ted++;

```
    orderPrice.remove(pes);
    orderVol.remove(pes);
    orderStartDate.remove(pes);
    orderEndDate.remove(pes);
    orderType.remove(pes);
    orderId.remove(pes);
    mListView.invalidateViews();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call 
    ListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the object reference of the list. Instead of doing that just change the data

```
adapter.orderPrice.clear();
adapter.orderPrice.addAll(mParent.orderPrice);
adapter.orderVol.clear();
adapter.orderVol.addAll(mParent.orderVol);
adapter.orderType.clear();
adapter.orderType.addAll(mParent.orderType);
adapter.orderId.clear();
adapter.orderId.addAll(mParent.orderId);
adapter.orderStartDate.clear();
adapter.orderStartDate.addAll(mParent.orderStartDate);
adapter.orderEndDate.clear();
adapter.orderEndDate.addAll(mParent.orderEndDate);
```

Also call notifyDataSetChanged() after you are done editing